# Can such a sequence be defined?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider any proper subset $S$ of the real numbers that contains infinitely many elements and that is bounded above. Call the set of upper bounds of this set $B_S.$

I defined the following sequences with a particular aim in mind.

1. Let $b_1 \in B_S.$ A strictly decreasing sequence $(b_n)$ such that for all $b \in B_S$, there exists an element $b_n$ in the sequence that satisfies $b_n \leq b.$
2. Let $s_1 \in S.$ A strictly increasing sequence $(s_n)$ such that for all $s \in S,$ there exists an element $s_n$ in the sequence that satisfies $s_n \geq s.$

---

I hereafter define a sequence of intervals $(I_n)$ by $I_n = [s_n,b_n].$

It follows from definition of the sequences $(s_n)$ and $(b_n)$ that $I_{n+1} \subset I_{n}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$

By NIP, there exists an element $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$x \in \bigcap_{i = 1}^{\infty} I_n.$$

Since for all $s \in S,$ there exists some element $s_n$ in $(s_n)$ such that $s \leq s_n,$ and for all $b \in B_S$ there exists some element $b_n$ in $(b_n)$ such that $b_n \leq b,$ and that $$s_i \leq x \leq b_j \quad \textrm{$\forall i,j \in \mathbb{N}$},$$ it follows that $$s \leq x \leq b, \quad \forall s \in S, b \in B_S.$$

Hence, $\operatorname{sup}S = x.$

Comment: It's not clear to me how you're defining these sequences. It seems you're specifying a property you want them to have, and simply willing them into existence.

Comment: Hey Theo. Ya. I guess to clarify, I meant that such a sequence can and does exist, and to choose one arbitrarily. Is that still too awkward?

Comment: Thanks for your input!

Comment: So you already know that such sequences exist? If so, then the proof seems fine.

Comment: Hey, Theo. I am essentially asking if such a sequence necessarily exists in a proper subset of the real numbers with infinitely many elements. My apologies if I am unclear. I recognize I need to improve my communication.

Comment: It depends on what else you're assuming about the real numbers. Such sequences definitely do exist, but **I think** some form of completeness is necessary to show their existence (I could definitely be wrong though!). Without it, the real line could essentially be "too long" for sequences to do the job properly.

Comment: Ya, good point. Maybe I should try and prove it without referring to the axiom of completeness. Thanks, Theo.

Comment: Hey, Theo. Would you take a brief look at this concise proof?: The Axiom of Completeness states that all proper subsets of the real numbers have a least upper bound (whether or not it is contained in the set). I will not have to refer to the fact that all proper subsets necessarily have a least upper bound. Here goes: **ALL PROPER SUBSETS OF THE REAL NUMBERS THAT CONTAIN INFINITELY MANY ELEMENTS ALSO  CONTAIN STRICTLY INCREASING SEQUENCES. IN OTHER WORDS, $\forall a \in A,$ $\exists a' \in A$ such that $a < a'.$**

Comment: Consider any proper subset $A$ of the real numbers that's bounded above and contains infinitely many elements. Either this set contains a least upper bound or does not. If it does, remove it from the set (the set remains with infinitely many elements). Suppose there exists an element $a \in A$ in the set $A$ such that all other elements $a' \in A$ satisfy $a' \leq a.$ It follows, then, that $a$ is a least upper bound, for $a' \leq a \leq b,$ for all $a' \in A$ and all upper bounds $b$ of $A.$ Hence, for all elements $a \in A,$ there exists $a' \in A$ such that $a < a'.$

Comment: The proof to show that all sets contain a strictly decreasing sequence is identical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89045/discussion-between-theo-bendit-and-rafael-vergnaud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is ... a mess. If you want to work with those sequences, you need to actually construct them. Given the difficulties - that is not the way.

Now, what you were supposed to do? Run a successive bisection argument. Start with an interval $[a_0,b_0]$ with lower endpoint $a_0=s-1$ for some element $s$ of $S$ and upper endpoint $b_0$ an upper bound of $S$. Look at the midpoint $\frac{a_0+b_0}{2}$ of this interval. Is it an upper bound for $S$? If yes, set $a_1=a_0$ and $b_1=\frac{a_0+b_0}{2}$. If no, set $a_1=\frac{a_0+b_0}{2}$ and $b_1=b_0$. Repeat this process.

At each step, we get an interval $[a_n,b_n]$ such that $b_n$ is an upper bound for $S$ and $a_n$ isn't. These intervals are nested, with lengths $\frac1{2^n}(b_0-a_0)$ tending to zero*. The intersection is therefore a single point $c$; we claim it's the least upper bound. Why? If $x>c$, then $x>b_n$ for some $n$ - since $b_n$ is an upper bound for $S$, $x$ can't be an element of $S$. Thus $c$ is an upper bound for $S$. But then, if $y<x$, then $y<a_n$ for some $n$; since $a_n$ isn't an upper bound, neither is $y$. Therefore, no upper bound of $S$ is less than $c$. Combining the two, $c$ is the least upper bound of $S$. Done.

*This is the Archimedean property. It may seem obvious, but it's not implied by the basic axioms of an ordered field. Completeness implies it, but of course we can't assume that here. So, what then? Unfortunately, there's no way around using the Archimedean property here; the nested interval theorem without it doesn't imply completeness. We'll just have to add it to our assumptions for this proposition.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you haven't even properly defined the sequences you're trying to use. Your latest revision drops any definition for the set that the upper endpoints are supposed to belong to, and you never had any reason for why the lower endpoints should be less than the upper endpoints. Without any control on the length of the intervals, there's no reason to expect them to go to zero - which means you could easily have multiple elements in the intersection. And your attempts to patch this invoke completeness, which we're not allowed to use. You simply haven't proved anything.

Comment: "by the Monotone Converge Theorem (which can be shown by assuming BWT)" - Ah, two more equivalents of completeness. You're assuming completeness to prove completeness. Failure.

Comment: The proposer  should have said that every $b_n\in B_S$ and that every $b_n>\min B_S=\inf S$ and that for every $b\in B_S$ such that $b>\inf S,$ there exists $b_n<b.$